# Linksys router p roblem

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, troubleshooting

I have a Linksys WRT54G V8 router. I connected it to my PC today. The Power LED does not light up but the Internet and Node ones do light up. But the router does not seem to be working. I put in the install CD and it asked me to see if the router was connected properly. It is connected properly. I cannot access the settings page too. It is unable to connect. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is it safe to assume you have a network cable coming from your modem (Internet connection) into the WAN port, and then another network cable going to your computer from one of the LAN ports?  Do you know if you are getting an IP address on your computer (Start->Control Panel->Network Connections->Local Area Connection...->Support tab)?

Answer (score 2):

I had this kind of problem with my WRT 54GC router several times.

Few hard resets helped me first time (hold reset button for 30 seconds). Note that router's IP address will change to 192.168.1.1

Half a year later this problem came again and I found that it was caused by (it is strange!) power supply. So I replaced it by a new one and all works fine since then.